# PHP Pattern searching

Tags: php

Im trying to search for nn/nnnnnn/nn in a file..

I have this

```
if (preg_match_all("([0-9]{6})", $file, $out)) {
echo "Match was found <br />";
print_r($out);
```

which deals with the centre 6 numbers but how do I get it to search for the whole pattern?
I get a little confused when i have to add the search strings together.
I know I have to do the following

([0-9]{2}) and / and ([0-9]{6}) and / and ([0-9]{2})

HOw do I add the search string as one?
Thanks in advance
Cheers
Mat

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `\d` for a digit instead:

```
preg_match_all("#(\d{2})/(\d{6})/(\d{2})#", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{6})\/([0-9]{2})/")
```

If searching `12/123456/12`, for example, it will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12/123456/12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

)
```

Comment: You're forgetting the end modifier slash. I'd also prefer to use another modifier, so you don't have to escape the slash: `preg_match_all("#([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{6})/([0-9]{2})#")`

Comment: Noticed that just before your comment!

Comment: @h2ooooooo You don't mean "modifier", you mean "delimiter"; just for future clarity. A "modifier" would be something you added onto the end of the string, outside the "delimiters" which mark the start and end of the pattern itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `#(\d{2})/(\d{6})/(\d{2})#`:

```
$file = '23/334324/23';
if (preg_match_all("#(\d{2})/(\d{6})/(\d{2})#", $file, $out)) {
    echo "Match was found <br />";
    print_r($out);
}
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23/334324/23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 334324
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 23
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `#([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{6})/([0-9]{2})#`:

```
if(preg_match_all("#([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{6})/([0-9]{2})#", $file, $out)) 
{
    echo "Match was found <br />";
    print_r($out);
}
```